# ag-grid How can I get row groups count in grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I use ag-grid context menu and want to disable some items if there is no any row groups in grid. So how can I get row groups count in grid?

I use ag-grid with Angular 5.

Comment: Are these enterprise functionalities for enterprise version? If so, you could post on the ag-grid community for enterprise version and you can get quick answers.

Comment: could you create a plunk for this? also, go through how to create [mcve]